# Link domain to specific Apache port

Tags: apache-http-server, centos, webserver, centos-6

I need to link a specific domain to a port in an Apache server.  I'm looking for something like this:

```
www.test.com     links to 127.0.0.1:80
www.sub.test.com links to 127.0.0.1:90
```

I already created two VirtualHosts in my httpd conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:90>
    ServerName www.sub.test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sub-test
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I try to access `www.sub.test.com` I got `port 80` website.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can assign the domains to ports, the default port for http is 80, so any address you specify without an explicit port will use port 80.

As for why you get the other website, as you don't specify a port, the browser uses port 80, and that is the only defined host for that port. The first defined `VirtualHost` is special as it will be selected of no entry matches.

Why are you using different ports? Just use port 80 for both names, and Apache will do what you probably want.

Comment: If I use the same port for both, when I access `www.test.com` I'm getting the website that I would get in `www.sub.test.com`.

Comment: You need ti remove the :90 from the secind VHOST

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying ti do is a.non-starter. (With respect f http and most protocols) a domain name / domain entry does not map to.an IP address.

If you are trying to run 2 websites off the same IP,  just do it - you dont need extra ports - The http protocol negotiates the site based on the domain, which is sent by the browser as part of the http (1.1) protocol.

If you need to connect a domain name to a service running on a port you need to implement a proxy of some sort where a connection made on port 80 is proxied across to port 90. This does not sound like what you want to do, but if it is, look at mod_proxy  for Apache.